# SqlException about UNION, INTERSECT and EXCEPT

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

Could someone help me with this exception? I don't understand what it means or how to fix it... It is an SqlException with the following message:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

I get it when running a query in pseudo code looking like this:

```
// Some filtering of data
var query = data.Subjects
            .Where(has value)
            .Where(has other value among some set of values);

// More filtering, where I need to have two different options
var a = query
            .Where(some foreign key is null);
var b = query
            .Where(some foreign key is not null)
            .Where(and that foreign key has a property which is what I want);
query = a.Union(b);

// Final filter and then get result as a list
var list = query
            .Where(last requirement)
            .ToList();
```

If I remove the `a.Union(b)` parts, it runs without the exception. So I know the error is there. But why do I get it? And how can I fix it? Am I doing something too crazy here? Have I misunderstood how to use the `Union` thing?

Basically what I have is some entities which have a foreign key to some other entity. And I need to get all the entities which either have that foreign key set to `null` or where that foreign entity fulfills some requirements.

Comment: It's an SqlException. I updated the question =)

Comment: Are you sure none of the queries is projecting anything (select)? I haven't run into this, but right now I don't recall if the Union I have done were linq2sql or against already retrieved data :(

Comment: But I don't see how that should be a problem, cause the queries work fine without the Union. Meaning, it has everything it needs and doesn't fail because of missing values or such. I have already ran into that error before, and this is not it :p

Comment: Re question; Yes and yes. Is that all sorted? I was AFK...

Comment: (did that comment belong to your answer?)

Comment: Anyways, problem is not sorted, but I need to do some more coding and thinking and trying out your suggestions. Working on it, but my brain is moving kind of slowly today.

Comment: Will update with more info and possibly a solution as soon as possible. Just have to get my brain cells into gear :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this looks like a problem with the generated SQL, you should try to use either an SQL Profiler, or use [this code for DebuggerWritter class](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Kris/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11) to write the SQL to your Output Window in Visual Studio.

The SQL error is normally caused by the fields retrieved for UNION is not the same for the 2 queries. For example, if the first query might have 3 fields, but the second query has 4 fields, this error will occur. So, seeing the generated SQL will definitely help in this case.

Answer (score 10):

Judging from the SQL error you listed you may be experiencing the same issue I was. Basically when Linq to SQL queries that use the Concat or Union extension method on two different queries it appears that there is a bug in Linq to SQL which optimizes each projection separately without regard to the fact that the projection must stay the same in order to accomplish the SQL Union.

References:

[LINQ to SQL produces incorrect TSQL when using UNION or CONCAT](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=355734)

[Linq to SQL Union Same Fieldname generating Error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/00e387f6-0633-4779-a2d7-af60e78857d5)

If this happens to be your problem as well I've found a solution that is working for me as shown below.

```
var queryA = 
    from a in context.TableA
    select new 
    {
        id,
        name,
        onlyInTableA,
    }

var queryB = 
    from b in context.TableB
    let onlyInTableA = default(string)
    select new 
    {
        id,
        name,
        onlyInTableA,
    }

var results = queryA.Union(queryB).ToList();
```

Comment: Note, that you have to define a new let statement for each computed value even if the actual literal values are the same in order to get this technique to work. So far this is the only reasonable solution I've found to the problem.

Comment: Here is some horrible news, it appears that not only has the .NET Framework 4.0 not corrected this issue but it also squashed the workaround that I presented above.

Comment: I agree, .NET 4 is optimsing even the let statements. However, an even more unsightly hack which seems to stop the optimiser in v4 is to perform a worthless operation on the let statement that does not alter it's result, like concatenating an emptry string or adding zero.

in this case, something like the following might work:
let onlyInTableA = default(string) + default(string)

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for the heads up. I'll have to remember that hack if I find myself cornered after upgrading to .NET 4.0. I'm hoping EF improves upon this eventually.

Comment: Fixed my issue by adding zero to the ID which was being projected twice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you perhaps write it in a single query?

```
.Where(row => row.ForeignKey == null || row.ForeignKey.SomeCondition);
```

There are also ways of merging expressions (`OrElse`), but that isn't trivial.

Not sure where the error comes from, though!

edit: haven't tested it, but this should be logically equivalent to a UNION:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAnyOf<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] predicates)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (predicates == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicates");
    if (predicates.Length == 0) return source.Where(row => false);
    if (predicates.Length == 1) return source.Where(predicates[0]);

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "row");
    Expression body = Expression.Invoke(predicates[0], param);
    for (int i = 1; i < predicates.Length; i++)
    {
        body = Expression.OrElse(body,
            Expression.Invoke(predicates[i], param));
    }
    return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param));
}
```

Comment: problem is that it is not just SomeCondition, but SomeCondition and also use of the WhereBetween method, which you helped me with a while ago, and stuff like that. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553443/c-linq2sql-creating-a-predicate-to-find-elements-within-a-number-of-ranges)

Comment: Perhaps you could use WhereAnyOf (above) with the main part of WhereBetween (or a version of WhereBetween that returns the predicate, rather than calling source.Where(predicate))

Comment: that looks promising and interesting... will try it out first thing tomorrow! (work is over, and have a bus to catch!)

Comment: Would swapping the OrElse with an AndAlso make it an WhereAllOf? And would returing the Expression.Lambda-and-so-forth directly instead of having it in a where, make it possible to combine them easier? Like if I could do two WhereAllOf, and then combine those with the WhereAnyOf and then do Where?

Comment: Why do you use `for` instead of `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

> query = a.Union(b);

Not a good idea to mutate captured variables...  Likely the cause of the error.

UPDATE: ok not

Here is another idea. The hint is in the error message.

```
var a = query
         .Where(some foreign key is null)
         .Select(x => x);
```

Or play by adding another 'fake' Where till they do become equal  :)

Comment: You are right in that the re-use introduces confusion, but note that none of those is captured...

Comment: He means - have var query2 = a.Union(b) and work with query2 downstream. However, I very-much doubt that this is the problem **on this occasion**, since it isn't actually captured.

Comment: @svish: can you test what marc said? That is what I meant. I suspect it being IQueryable may cause a problem, just a hunch  :)

Comment: I don't see what is supposed to be a problem here. I know about problems in foreach loops and such, but here I just update variable kind of? Not much different than doing `string s = "test"; s = s.ToUpper();`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't get it. Added a Select doesn't help anything?

Answer (score 0):

I would call `data.GetCommand(query)` and analyze the resulting `DbCommand` (especially the generated SQL string). That should give you a clue to what goes wrong.

There is no projection going on anywhere so I would expect both target lists to be the same.

You could try to reduce your query to a smaller one that still doesn't work. Start with `query.Union(query)` (this should at least work). Than add your `Where` calls one by one to see when it stops working.

It must be one of your `Where` calls that adds extra columns to your select list.

Comment: already looked at the sql, although I got it during debugging. Copied it and pasted it into sql manager in a new query. And I get the same error there. Problem is the query is quite large, and I am not very stable on reading sql...

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance passing in a value to the 'select' side in a variable, or are you returning the same field more than once? SP1 introduced a bug where it tries to 'optimize' out such things and that can cause union queries to break (due to the query parts 'optimizing' out different passed-in params).

If you post your actual query rather than pseudo code it makes it easier to identify if this is the case.

(And a workaround if this is the case is to materialize the individual parts first and then do a client-side (L2O) union).

Answer (score 0):

jpierson has the problem summarised correctly.
I also had the problem, this time caused by some literals in the select statement:
`Dim results = (From t in TestDataContext.Table1 _

Where t.ID = WantedID _

Select t.name, SpecialField = 0, AnotherSpecialField = 0, t.Address).Union _

From t in TestDataContext.Table1 _

Where t.SecondID = WantedSecondID _

Select t.name, SpecialField = 1, AnotherSpecialField = 0, t.Address)`

The first sub-query of "SpecialField = 0" and the "AnotherSpecialField = 0" were optimised, resulting in one field instead of two being used in the union, which will obviously fail.
I had to change the first query so that the SpecialField & AnotherSpecialField had different values, much like in the second sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had an issue with this. Using Sql 08 i had two table functions that returned an int and a string in both cases. I created a complex object and used linq to attempt a UNION. Had an IEqualityComparer to do the comparision. All compiled fine, but crashed with a unsupported overload. Ok, i realised the problem discussed seemed to smack of defered execution. So i get the collections, and place ToList(), then do the UNION and it is all good. Not sure if this is helpful, but it works for me

Comment: Well, that I know. But what you are doing is to do the UNION locally. That may or may not be a good idea depending on your circumstances.