# SQL Linq Question

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have the following working TSQL query in ms SQL 2008

```
SELECT
    Date,
    COUNT(click) AS clicks,
    COUNT(sale) AS sales,
    count(lead) as leads
FROM
(
SELECT ClickDate as date ,ID AS click ,CAST(NULL AS int) AS  sale , CAST(null as int) as lead
FROM clicks

UNION ALL

SELECT Date,null, ID ,NULL
FROM sales

UNION ALL

SELECT Date,null, NULL ,ID
FROM leads

) t
GROUP BY Date
```

How would i convert this to LINQ to SQL?
I wrote this LINQ but it doesn't work.

```
public class mydata
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int? click { get; set; }
    public int? sale { get; set; }
    public int? lead { get; set; }
}

var clicks = from c in Clicks
             select new mydata
             { 
                 date = c.ClickDate, click = c.ID,  sale = null, lead = null
             };

var sales = from s in Sales
            select new mydata
            {
                 date = s.Date, click = null, sale = s.ID, lead = null
            };

var leads = from l in Leads
            select new mydata
            {
                date = l.Date, click = null, sale = null, lead = l.ID
            };

var v = clicks.Concat(sales).Concat(leads);

var res = from x in v
       group x by x.date into xg
       select new
       {
                 date = xg.Key, clicks = xg.Count(z => z.click != null)
       };
}
```

How do i correct this LINQ query?

**Update:**
i Modified the LINQ query based on David B recommendation.

i'm still getting the following error:
"All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

Comment: What goes wrong with your query?

Comment: 1. grouping error "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

2. error talking about not allowed null values

3. error talking about kg.Count() , "cannot convert int to bool".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the anonymous types in the projections are not identical... ID is `int` in one and `Nullable<int>` in another.

Instead of using an anonymous type in your projections, use this:

```
public class ConcatTarget
{
  public DateTime TheDate {get;set;}
  public int? ID {get;set;}
  public string sale {get;set;}
  public string lead {get;set;}
}
```

Even though no instances are actually constructed, LinqToSql uses the class's shape to translate the query.

As for `Count`, perhaps you meant `.Count(x => x.Prop != null)` ?

---

Ok, apparently you've hit upon a buggy translation behavior as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650847/linq2sql-help-with-sqlexception-about-union-intersect-and-except/1171407#1171407).

What's happening is the sql translator sees the null assignments, and throws them away.  This causes an incorrect number of sql columns to be selected between the sets.

Here's a possible workaround:

```
int? myNull = null;

var clicks =
  from c in Clicks 
  select new mydata 
  {  
    date = c.ClickDate,
    click = c.ID,
    sale = c.ID + myNull,
    lead = myNull + c.ID  //note - expressions must be unique
  };
```

The basic idea is to create unique expressions the query translator can't throw away.  This is harder than it sounds (above is my ninth attempt).

---

Here's the other two tables:

```
var sales = from s in Sales 
        select new mydata 
        { 
             date = s.Date,
             click = s.ID + myNull,
             sale = s.ID,
             lead = myNull + s.ID
        }; 

var leads = from l in Leads 
        select new mydata 
        { 
            date = l.Date,
            click = l.ID + myNull,
            sale = myNull + l.ID,
            lead = l.ID 
        };
```

If you had more than 2 columns-to-be-nulled, you could resort to subtraction,  division, multiplication, etc.

Comment: thx for the help , i tried to do this , you can see my updated code above , im still getting a error.

Comment: Yes , i saw that the query is translated in the wrong way.
I tried your solution but i'm not sure i understand how to apply it to the rest of the tables(sales , leads..). Wow this is harder than i thought.

Answer (score 0):

David's correct about the first two issues.  For your final problem (3), Count() does not work like it does in SQL.  It expects a predicate that returns a bool.  Your using it with ints (i.e. z.click, z.sales, etc.)